# Private message feature

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, messaging

I would like to know if it's possible to have a Personal Message feature in SU. Sometimes I want to email a user or even a mod but I don't think it's possible. I think it could be usefull to share more information or link, references and other stuff.

Also, if some money's needed, we can donate like 10$ or 50$ and get access to a secret place on SU to share info with mod, admin... or a Gold badge (Donation)! And also, get a free T-shirt when it's like 50$

Answer (score 4):

You can flag for moderator attention, if you want a mod to look at something. Anything from a reconsideration after a wrongful close, answers that aren't answers, spam (flag as spam as well), recalculating your rep, suspicious votes.

If you would like to "message" another user, you can leave a comment on their answer for clarification or such.

If you want to message another user on a post, but they aren't the one's who posted, you can [prepend their username with an at sign (@example) so that they will see it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). But only if they've already left a comment on the post you're replying to or have recently edited said post.

You can also see if they're in the chat rooms.

Ultimately, if a user does not leave contact details on their profile they do not want to be contacted.

A private messaging feature would then completely disrespect this basic door sign of unsolicited communication.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I meant by PM (Private Messaging) a real PM... Like when you log in SU, you can see that you have 2-3-4 new emails in your inbox. You can get your notifications, replys, comments and also PM. I would definitly like this feature!

Comment: @r0ca You could check the profile page, perhaps there would be an email address entered to which you can send an email to.

Comment: I don't really want this feature myself because SU seems to function fine without it. However, if I did want to be contacted, I personally would feel better about using private messages than sharing contact details such as email. The user could always opt out (or opt-in only). But I think it would add a significant extra workload to the servers without any real reason.