# Allow "private" messages between users?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Private message feature](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1197/private-message-feature)

It would be a useful feature to have a button sitting on every user page that would allow one user to contact another in a private way, without having to use chat. It would be like sending a short e-mail within Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm going to put this slightly more explicitly this time... please stop asking so many meta questions without doing any research. Before asking any more questions, check on this site and on [metase]. The number of very basic questions you are asking which could easily be figured out with some simple research is becoming abusive.

Comment: To add onto @nhinkle, you may also want to take advantage of our chat system, particularly Root Access, our room. Users are there almost 24/7 who will eventually get back to you with an answer to almost any question http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: @nhinkle Ok, fellas, thank you, I will make use of the chat room. I didn't know that chat room existed. Maybe you should send each newly signed up user an e-mail telling them about the blog, the most important chat rooms and other basic things like those. Thanks again for being so tolerant, I'm embarrassed...

Comment: A lot of this is in the [FAQ](http://meta.superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been requested multiple times, and been [denied just as many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) on Meta Stack Overflow. At this point, I doubt it will be implemented with this many times being [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). You can always create a private chat room, or see [other ways to contact user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)s.

If you look at that post, it's been requested about 15+ times to no avail, and has been consistently requested since the site started.